In a phrase like "the type of girl who..." what does the relative pronoun refer to?
In my current translation project I have several cases where in German I want to refer to "die Art" ("the kind/type of") a noun followed by a relative clause, and I am not sure which noun the relative pronoun should refer to. For example:

This feels like the kind of tree that is protected by the Vaettir.


A heroine is not the type of girl who is afraid of mice.

Should it be "... nicht die Art Mädchen, die sich vor Mäusen fürchtet" or "... das sich vor Mäusen fürchtet?"


die Art Mann
der Typ Frau

In appositions of this type, the bold part is the nucleus and the part in italics is the dependant. Relative clauses are expected to agree with the nucleus. Some examples (via DWDS corpora):

Ein Mann, der Angst vor mir hat, ist genau die Art Mann, die mich nicht interessiert.
Dr. Conrad ist die Art Mann, die nach einem langen Arbeitstag einen schmackhaften Truthahn einkauft, das Kind zu Bett bringt und gleich darauf eine neue Verführungstechnik an der eigenen Frau anwendet.
Emma Peel steht für einen besonders starken und emanzipierten Typ Frau, der sich in den späteren 1960er Jahren in Europa entwickelte.
Ich bin auch eher der Typ Frau, der sich nicht übertrieben schminkt und aufbretzelt, und mit 15 kommt dann ja noch die Frage hinzu: Wie ziehe ich mich an?

However, there are examples of attraction to be found, where the grammatical features of the dependant take over.

Er wirkte wie die Art Mann, der seine haarigen Füße in Treckingsandalen zwängt […] (Schaap, Hotel Istanbul)
Sie gehört zu dem Typ Frauen, die irgendwann auf Botox zurückgreifen […] (Borowitz, Die Tage vor der Hochzeit)


"Relative clauses are expected to agree with the nucleus" I would have thought the relative clause has to agree with whatever it relates to. The relative pronoun can refer to Art or to Frau. The semantic difference is tough to tell because the extension of the relative clause would be the same, so differences would have to refer to the intension. You mention a semantic pattern - attraction vs. not. Do you have an explanation of that? Is that a consistent pattern?

From a syntactic perspective, the fact that the relative clause agrees with the nucleus should be sufficient. But note that if the nucleus is left out, the result becomes ungrammatical: er ist *(der Typ) Mann, der mir Angst macht. Semantically, cases such as the following seem to make sense only with the relative clause referring to the nucleus, not the dependant: die Anlage benutzt vier verschiedene Arten Malz, die unter anderem unterschiedlich stark getorft sind.

The classic example for attraction would be ein Kilo Äpfel kosten (instead of kostet).
